# How to say that my pet sleeps "next to my legs"?

Tags: word-request

I have a pet that often sleeps *next to my legs in my bed*.

How can I say it properly in English? Is there a neat idiom for it? I want to sound natural and I don't think the above expression is natural.

Comment: I would say the dog sleeps "at my feet"

Comment: Are you saying your pet is **in contact** with your legs when sleeping? What kind of pet is it?

Comment: It sometimes is with contact with my legs, sometimes it is 15 cm next to my legs. It's a cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At my feet**

can mean literally next to one's feet, but also **below one's waist**

> **Around my legs**

means **on**, **next to**, **under**, **in the general vicinity of** your legs.

Comment: Related: __at the foot of the bed__ is roughly equivalent to __at my feet__.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this portion of Rudyard Kipling's poem:

> Pussy will rub my knees with her head
>   Pretending she loves me hard;
>   But the very minute I go to my bed
>   Pussy runs out in the yard,
>   And there she stays till the morning-light;
>   So I know it is only pretend;
>   But Binkie, **he snores at my feet** all night,
>   And he is my Firstest Friend!

I hope this answers your question. You can find the complete poem [here](http://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/just_so_stories.html).

Answer (score 1):

My cat often *cuddles* with me in bed. Her favorite spot is to *spoon* behind my kneecaps while I'm <strike>laying</strike> lying on my side. I don't think there's a name for that spot you make behind them, when you flex your knees.

***Cuddles up to my*** [legs] - and spoons [them/it].

Comment: I think, or hope, you mean _lying_ on your side.

Comment: I think I hope I meant the other one actually ;)